# Using Input from Scanner to Assign Class

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Library {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
    /*
     * Patron class: name + 3 books
     * Book class: author + title
     */
    Book TwelveYears = new Book ("12 Years a Slave", "Solomon Northup");
    Book Diary = new Book ("The Diary of John Smith", "John Smith");
    Book Fahrenheit451 = new Book ("Fahrenheit 451", "Ray Bradbury");
    Book Gatsby = new Book ("The Great Gatsby", "Fitzgerald");
    Book Antigone = new Book ("12 Years a Slave", "Sophocles");




    System.out.println("Welcome to library account management! Here is a list of books to check out: " +TwelveYears.getBookTitle()+", "+Diary.getBookTitle()+", "+Fahrenheit451.getBookTitle()+", "+Gatsby.getBookTitle()+", "+Antigone.getBookTitle()+".");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name!");
    String enteredName = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your first book! Enter it exactly as seen above.");
    String book1 = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your second book!");
    String book2 = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your third book!");
    String book3 = sc.nextLine();
    Patron patron1 = new Patron(enteredName, book1, book2, book3);
    book1 = //line I need help on
    System.out.println("Here are the books you are checking out: " +book1+ ", " +book2+ ", " +book3+ ".");





    }

}
```

Here, I'm trying to take the book1 variable, and assosciate it with a member of a class properly. I think the best way to explain what I'm trying to do here is with an example: if book1 entered by the user is "12 Years a Slave" then book1's value would be "TwelveYears", one of the class definitions near the start of the code, so in the future, I could use an accessor/mutator method like book1.getAuthor.

I'm just learning java, so I lack the ways to properly explain this most likely, so I apologize, but any help would be greatly appreciated, and I would be happy to answer any questions if what I'm trying to do here, but I hope I was clear enough.

Thank you!

Comment: book1.getAuthor() won't work since book1 is an instance of a String. If that is what you want.

Comment: do u mean how to build your code in a a structured manner to retrieve the book based on what the user entered?  like if user enter book name or author u return the relevant books?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to decide which object to create based on a String, you can simply do a bunch of checks on the book titles and determine which object to create. Assuming `TwelveYears` and `GreatGatsby` both inherit from `Book`, then you can do:

```
Book unknownBook;
switch(bookTitleScanned)
{
    case("Twelve Years a Slave")
        unknownBook = new TwelveYears();
    case("Great Gatsby")
        unknownBook = new GreatGatsby();
    ...
}
```

Here your `Book` reference can point to `TwelveYears` and `GreatGatsby` because of [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

But here's probably a better way to do what you wanted:

Assuming all the objects for your purpose are fairly similar (in your example you have `book`s like `TwelveYears` and `GreatGatsby`), it might be easier if you simply write one class, say `Book`, and let that class do all the handling, instead of creating separate classes.

Then you simply create instances of `Book` class, assign the book names as attributes to these instances, and collect them in some kind of [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) object, which will make your code much more flexible and reusable (hey you can loop over your `Book`s if you put them in say an `ArrayList`).

Concretely, your `Book` class can have an attribute say `bookName`, and methods like

```
public void getBookName()
{
    return bookName;
}
```

or even:

```
public void handleParticularBook()
{
   if (bookName.equals("GreatGatsby"))
      System.out.println("My favorite book!");
   else if ...
}
```

Comment: I believe OP's question is "Using Input from Scanner to Assign Class", so I assume multiple classes are available.

Comment: Thank you for your well written answer! It helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

place all the  books in `ArrayList<Book>`. Iterate `ArrayList` and use `book1.equals(a1.get(i).getBookName)` if matches the `book1=a1.get(i).getBookTitle`